# Cannot use the local variable before it is declared

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Must be missing something basic here, but trying to make a simple calculator app, heres a piece of my code, when I try to run it its giving me;

"Error  1   Cannot use local variable 'xxxxxx' before it is declared. The declaration of the local variable hides the field xxxxx

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    double total1 = 0;
    double total2 = 0;
    bool plusBtnPressed = false;
    bool minusBtnPressed = false;
    bool timesBtnPressed = false;
    bool divideBtnPressed = false;


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(plusBtnPressed == true) {
            total2 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }

        else if (minusBtnPressed == true) {
            total2 = total1 - double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }

        else if (divideBtnPressed == true) {
            total2 = total1 / double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }
        else if (timesBtnPressed == true) {
            total2 = total1 * double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }


        bool plusBtnPressed = false;
        bool minusBtnPressed = false;
        bool timesBtnPressed = false;
        bool divideBtnPressed = false;
    }


    private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total1 += double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        plusBtnPressed = true;
        minusBtnPressed = false;
        divideBtnPressed = false;
        timesBtnPressed = false;
        txtDisplay.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't write `bool plusBtnPressed = false;` in `button3_Click` but only `plusBtnPressed = false;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the `bool` from `bool plusBtnPressed = false;` within the `button3_Click` event handler, and do this for the other 3 variables.

You're currently declaring new variables and this has the effect of hiding the class members. The compiler also thinks you're using those declared variables earlier in the function which is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead,

```
    bool plusBtnPressed = false;
    bool minusBtnPressed = false;
    bool timesBtnPressed = false;
    bool divideBtnPressed = false;
```

Put,

```
    plusBtnPressed = false;
    minusBtnPressed = false;
    timesBtnPressed = false;
    divideBtnPressed = false;
```

In your event handler.